# How to use Holder inequality in PDE?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reading Qing Han,& Fanghua Lin’s *elliptic partial differential equations* . I can’t understand this step using Holder inequality.  Could anyone help me explain how this inequality applied here? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it’s Cauchy-Schwarz inequality used here.
\begin{align}
8|\eta D_i\eta D_j u D_{ij}u|&=|4 D_i\eta D_j u\cdot 2 \eta D_{ij}u|\\&\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(16 {D_i\eta}^2 {D_j u}^2+4{\eta}^2{D_{ij}u}^2\right)\\&=8 {D_i\eta}^2 {D_j u}^2+2 {\eta}^2{D_{ij}u}^2.
\end{align}
Hence we know 
$$8\eta\sum_{i,j=1}^n D_i\eta D_j u D_{ij}u\geq -8|D\eta|^2|D u|^2-2\eta^2\sum_{i,j=1}^n(D_{ij}u)^2.$$